# Mocha and Selenium WebDriver error thrown while assertion

Tags: node.js, selenium

I developing a web program with [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) methodology. Therefore, tests are using [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) library. But I wonder my program doesn't work correctly. Following is source codes.

public/index.html:

```
<h1 class="hello">Hello, world!</h1>
```

test/test.js:

```
'use strict'
var assert = require('assert')
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until

var driver;

before(() => {
    driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .build()
})

describe('Index page', () => {
    before(() => {
        driver.get('http://localhost:8080/')
    })

    it('should show hello greetings', () => {
        let hello = driver.findElement(By.css('h1.hello'))
        assert.equal(hello.getText(), 'Hello, world!')
    })
})
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^2.5.3"
    "selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server public",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And I've run following command.

```
C:\Projects\foobar>npm install
```

So, when I run all tests with `npm test` command, it always failed regardless to `npm start` command was run or not.

```
C:\Projects\foobar>npm test

> foobar@1.0.0 test C:\Projects\foobar
> mocha



  Index page
    1) should show hello greetings


  0 passing (62ms)
  1 failing

  1) Index page should show hello greetings:
     AssertionError: ManagedPromise {
  flow_:
   ControlFlow {
     propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
     activeQueue_:
      TaskQueue {
     == 'Hello, world!'
      at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\foobar\test\test.js:22:16)
      at callFn (C:\Projects\foobar\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:326:21)
      at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Projects\foobar\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:319:7)
      at Runner.runTest (C:\Projects\foobar\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:422:10)
      at C:\Projects\foobar\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:528:12
      at next (C:\Projects\foobar\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:342:14)
      at C:\Projects\foobar\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:352:7
      at next (C:\Projects\foobar\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:284:14)
      at Immediate._onImmediate(C:\Projects\foobar\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:320:5)


npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I think the main issue is in `hello.getText()` snippet. The `getText()` method couldn't get text of *hello* element.

Comment: `h1.hello` is not a valid query..

Comment: `findElement(By.css('h1.hello'))`. In your `html` the `h1` does not have a `class` attribute with the value `hello`. Since it can find the element I'm assuming you forgot to put this in the `html` sample?

Comment: @cviejo @RemcoW Thank you. However, when I modify to `<h1 class="hello">Hello, world!</h1>`, there is no difference.

Comment: Update your question to reflect that change, please

Comment: @cviejo Thanks. I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most driver operations are asynchronous and return a promise, not the actual return value of that operation. In your case you should change `findElement` but also `getText` to work in that manner. Also, you should set a timeout since the default one is set to 2000 ms and most pages won't have finished loading by then. Try this:

```
'use strict'
var assert    = require('assert');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var By    = webdriver.By;
var until = webdriver.until;

var driver;

before(function () {
    driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .build();
});

describe('Index page', function () {

    this.timeout(5000);

    before(function () {
        driver.get('http://localhost:8080/');
    });

    it('should show hello greetings', function (done) {
        driver.findElement(By.css('h1.hello'))
            .then(elem => elem.getText() )
            .then(text => assert.equal(text, 'Hello, world!') )
            .then(done);
    });
});
```

Note that arrow function don't define their own `this` object. You have to use regular callback functions to access `this.timeout`. Their use is, in any case, discouraged in mocha, see [following](https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions):

> Passing arrow functions to Mocha is discouraged. Their lexical binding of the this value makes them unable to access the Mocha context, and statements like this.timeout(1000); will not work inside an arrow function.

Comment: Okay. I see. However, when I run test without starting server, there are no errors. Why?

Comment: There was a typo in my answer, port `3001` should've been `8080`. Fixed. If the test is passing the server is up, double-check that, please.

Comment: I checked. But it always passes regardless the port is 8080 or not.

Comment: That's simply not possible, task would timeout and element wouldn't be found (and of course not reproduceable on my end). Please open `'http://localhost:8080/'`on your browser and check that you have the **exact** same code as above.

Comment: You most probably have still `{}` around some arrow functions. That causes the tests to pass. Using square brackets will result in those functions not returning any value (promises in this case) and therefore pass all tests. Again, either copy the **exact code** above as it is or pay attention to that.

Comment: Sorry. I should go to sleep now. See you tomorrow!

Comment: Thank you. I solved with some code modifications. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help